# How to track multiple object location?

Tags: opencv

I need to track multiple objects, some color objects, attached on human body; All same color. I can track one object through `Threshold image` and `Moment` but when I use more than one object the computed `Moment` is something between those two or three. I need to have `xy` coordinate of each ones. Actually, after all, I want to do some analysis on those sequences of coordinates.
I'm using VS2010, OpenCV 2.3.1, Win7 x64.

Comment: you could try `particle filtering` / `condensation`.
You will have to implement it yourself, but it's not so hard to implement.

Answer (score 3):

You have to compute the moments for each blob alone. To accomplish this, you can use [`cv::findContours`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) to get a *descriptor* for each blob in the form of its contour, then use it to compute its moments. In the code snippet below, inspired by [this example](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/moments/moments.html), it is shown how one would compute the mass centers of each blob using this approach.

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;

// Find contours
cv::findContours(img, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0));

// Get the moments
std::vector<Moments> mu(contours.size() );
for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    mu[i] = moments(contours[i], false);

// Get the mass centers:
std::vector<cv::Point2f> mc(contours.size());
for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    mc[i] = Point2f(mu[i].m10/mu[i].m00 , mu[i].m01/mu[i].m00);
```